# Python remove same string link into array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python array that contains more URL link as string format.
Some of this URL string are equal:

```
[u'it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'/it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'it/crag/751/alonte.html', u'/it/crag/751/alonte.html']
```

how can I remove the equal string URL?
Thanks

Comment: [Convert to a set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
l = [u'it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'/it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'it/crag/751/alonte.html', u'/it/crag/751/alonte.html']
result = [j for i, j in enumerate(l) if all(j not in k for k in l[i + 1:])]
```

Comment: I suppose it works - but it's *remarkably* inefficient compared to `list(set(l))`

Comment: @JonClements Of course it's slower than `set` but set doesn't remove substrings, _as it shouldn't_, and that was the question :)

Comment: Why not `{'/' + el.lstrip('/') for el in l}` then? (that also standardises duplicates to retain a leading `/` if required.

Comment: @JonClements Fair, but this would work on general substrings, not just `/` case. One example that would rule out your solution is `.htm`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned use a `set`, because in a set there can not be duplicate

which translates into

```
s = set([u'it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'/it/crag/830/ai-falconi.html', u'it/crag/751/alonte.html', u'/it/crag/751/alonte.html'])
```

Comment: Please check the `len(s)`, its still `4`